# how to create browse button and get its further functionality in edit mode in PQGrid in Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I m using `PQGrid` in `Spring MVC Java` and have stopped at getting the browse button or file select option on UI.

I put the code for browse button on `colM[1]` with `render function` by returning `input type = 'file'`.

When I click on edit button, the browse button disappears from screen. I can only see the text in edit mode. But, when the page gets loaded, I can see and that button and that too without clicking on edit button.

And I want button when `colM[1].editable=true`. Its not getting possible in this case. Even, I have added `refreshRow` function, but it goes in loop and gives error on console and stopped.

I have googled a lot but didnt find anything. Please help me.